# DataGridCell change if number positive or negative

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

i have a DataGridTextColumn that accepts numbers from a database table called Numbers. If the number in cell is positive than i want the next DataGridTextColumn to have the word "Positive" inside. I tried with IConverter Styles but still dont know how to do it right.I hope someone can help me.

This is my code so far:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="false" CanUserAddRows="True" Margin="5,5,10,5" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Numbers}">

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Num}" Header="Number" FontSize="16"/>

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Positive/Negative" FontSize="16">

                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Amount, Converter={StaticResource PositiveNegativeConverter}}"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid>
```

I also have this inside Resources:

```
    <local:PositiveNegativeConverter x:Key="PositiveNegativeConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

My Converter looks like this:

```
class PositiveNegativeConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool revert = (parameter as string).StartsWith("-");

        string stringValue = value as string;
        string compareValue = parameter as string;

        if (revert)
        {
            return "Negative";
        }
        else
            return "Positive";
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have to add a style for that, just add the converter to the Binding in the DataGridTextColumn.

Something like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Num, Converter={StaticResource PositiveNegativeConverter}}" Header="Number" FontSize="16"/>
```

Comment: I get a NullReferenceException in:   bool revert = (parameter as string).StartsWith("-"); Maybe becouse Num returns double numbers and not strings?

Comment: Oh now it works... i should first convert the value in String with the ToString() method.. thx Cristian

Comment: I accepted Cristians answer, but only of curiosity is there any possibility to show the texts in different color? Positive with Green and negative with BLue color?

Comment: For that you can add another converter for the Foreground Property :)

Comment: But can i use 2 Converter inside the Binding?

Comment: The second converter is something like this:
<DataGridTextColumn Foreground="{Binding Num, Converter={StaticResource PositiveNegativeForegroundConverter}}" Header="Number" FontSize="16"/>
It binds to another property (FOreground) which controls the color of the text.

Comment: Hmm..i get: Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=Amount; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridTextColumn' (HashCode=13220972); target property is 'Foreground' (type 'Brush')

Comment: i am going to open new question, because you answered my firts question

Comment: That means the DataGridTextColumn does not have that prop. You must add a TextBlock as the data template. Hope this helps.